# Where to put grid layout in SUSY/SMACSS structure

Tags: susy, smacss

say on the about page you have 3 column grid and on the home page you have a four column grid, in which file within the css architecture should these styles be placed to layout these pages, should each page have a layout css?

Answer (score 0):

I, personally, only use one layout file and put whole pages layout styles here, more easier to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

Good question. However, adding a specific css file for specific pages would greatly negate the purpose/power of SMACCS.  All of your layout structure should be in one 'layout' css file or better yet defined within a custom (or not) mixin which you can call based inside of a module or overall layout.